# vim text-object: place of the cursor

Tags: vim, textselection, text-cursor

I've got a little question that's been running through my mind; when I use the text object selection, I find sometimes the cursor's positionning doesn't matter, and sometimes it does. For instance:

```
a dummy text "between quotes"
a dummy text (between brackets)
```

If I place my cursor at the beginning of each line, and if I do the command:

- 1st line: vi" -> it selects directly the text between the ";
- 2nd line: vi( -> it selects nothing; the cursor has to be between the brackets in order for vim to select the text.

I took a look at the :h text-objects but I can't see why it's behaving like this. Any idea what commands depends on the cursor's position to work? Or at least how to understand the help?

Thank you!